# Django Tastypie 'All_WITH_RELATIONS' is not defined

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I'm trying to use resource filtering in Django Tastypie however I get an error when I try to import 'ALL_WITH_RELATIONS'. Below is the full error:

```
api/resources.py", line 309, in Meta
'receipt' : All_WITH_RELATIONS,
NameError: name 'All_WITH_RELATIONS' is not defined
/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 319, in resolve
for pattern in self.url_patterns:
```

My code:

`from tastypie.resources import ALL, ALL_WITH_RELATIONS`

I cannot seem to find anything about this error online, nor do I understand what I could be doing wrong. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was trivial, `All_WITH_RELATIONS` needed to be `ALL WITH RELATIONS`.